# Create user-specific Integration Cards in SAP Work Zone

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, manifest.json, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-business-application-studio

I'm currently developing UI Integration Cards for SAP Work Zone (for HR) in Business Application Studio. The goal of the Integration Cards is to show data (e.g. meetings from Outlook calendar, Teams messages, etc.) from different Microsoft services, with the help of Microsoft Graph. I used Open Connectors to create an instance of Microsoft Graph, and it was no problem showing my personal Outlook meetings and Teams messages in the integration card. But when I log in with a different user into SAP Work Zone, the integration card still only shows my personal meetings and not the meetings from the logged-in user.

**Is it possible to create dynamic Integration Cards that show user-specific information (from Microsoft services)?**

Ideas I had so far (and the problem(s) why I didn't try the idea yet):

1. Instead of using Open Connectors, programmatically change/create the manifest.json (I don't know if it's possible and if yes, how it is possible to programmatically create or change the manifest.json in Business Application Studio)
2. Call some sort of function or script file in the manifest.json to dynamically create strings for the JSON values (How do I integrate functions or files in the manifest.json and is it even possible?)
3. Somehow grab the information about the logged-in user (when loading the Integration Card in Work Zone) and use the given information about the user to create the authorization data needed to request the meetings and messages from Microsoft Graph (Is the logged-in SAP user even connected to the Microsoft user?)

I already tried to integrate a JavaScript module file in the manifest.json, but it didn't execute the code in the file and instead just showed the name of the file.

*If more information is needed to answer this question, I will happily try to provide more information.​ Any help or idea is welcome. I will try to edit the question if I find anything useful or the question gets answered.*